# Add COM library reference in MonoDevelop

Tags: dll, reference, mono, monodevelop

I have downloaded a .exe file that when executed (in wine) it puts two dll's in the system32 folder and a dll in the "Common files/App-name/" folder.

In theory, the installing of this file creates a tab in Visual Studio that appears when referencing and it is a COM library.

I have tried to reference these dll's in my console project but I get a message of "Is not a valid .Net assembly".

Is there something I can do?

Comment: Mono+Wine? It is not Windows ang .NET. You should port the application without the COM part. http://www.mono-project.com/Guidelines:Application_Portability

Answer (score 0):

MonoDevelop does not have support for adding COM references directly. You will have to use [tlbimp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx%28VS.80%29.aspx) to generate a wrapper dll, then reference that. This is essentially what VS does transparently when you reference a native COM dll.

Comment: I have executed this exe (without params) with my .exe file (without params) but it says that is not a valid type of library. 

Also I have tried with one of the dll's that the my .exe contains, but when I try to reference the output in my project I get the "Is not a valid .Net assembly"